# VBA Cannot execute in all worksheet

Tags: vba

Please help, this code only runs in one worksheet if code to consider "Range to ActivateSheet.Paste". I want to run this to all sheets, but when I input the code, below, there's an appearing error "Next Without For". Appreciate any insights :)

Dim ws As Worksheet

```
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
    
    Range("G25").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("E25").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1:E1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveCell.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Next ws
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Just figure out the solution. Removing Application.CutCopyMode = False and ActiveCell.Activate, placing E